# Add value from Dictionary to ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, actionlink

I'm trying to send a list of objects with ActionLink. The Key works but i get nothing in the list even though it contains objects.
What am i doing wrong?

My model contains a Dictionary where Key is a string and Value a List

```
@foreach (var clinic in Model.Clinics)
{
    <div>@clinic.Key</div>
    @Html.ActionLink(clinic.Key, "LoadSelectedClinicView", "Clinic", new {customerName=clinic.Key, dictionaryVal=clinic.Value}, null)
}
```

My LoadSelectedClinicView looks like this

```
public PartialViewResult LoadSelectedCustomerView(string clinicName, List<MyObject> dictionaryVal)
        {
            foreach(var item in dictionaryVal){}
        }
```

Comment: Please show the code for your MyObject class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Html helpers do not support using a list of objects as the parameter of a Url route so this will not work:

```
@Html.ActionLink(clinic.Key, "LoadSelectedClinicView", "Clinic", new {customerName=clinic.Key, dictionaryVal=clinic.Value}, null)
```

You will need to construct the URL yourself. You could write a simple static method which accepts a root Url and a list and returns a query string with the parameters concatenated with a & delimiter. String.join is a handy way to do this:

```
string.Join("&",list)
```

You need to be careful that the URL doesn't exceed the maximum length of a Url which is something like 2,083 characters long.